# ODE45 in Octave

Tags: octave, ode

I am pretty beginner in Octave. I try to solve an ODE. The code is below.
I got always the following error message:
error: operator /: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x1, op2 is 0x0)

Do You have any idea what should I modify?

Thanks a lot

```
close all;
clear all;
Ap = 5.66;
mp_gl = 5;
alfa_l = 2.5;
c_gl = 3200;
c_m = 3800;
T_inf = 17;
t_1_SI=3600;
m_must=1070;
T_m_0 = 18;
#
#
t_ODE1=[0, t_1_SI];
# Solve ODE
function dtT_must = ODE1(t,T_must)
    global alfa_l;
    global T_inf;
    global Ap;
    global c_gl;
    global mp_gl;
    global c_m;
    global m_must;
    dtT_must = (alfa_l*(T_inf-T_must)*Ap-c_gl*mp_gl)/(c_m*m_must);
endfunction
[t,T_must] = ode45 (@ODE1, t_ODE1, T_m_0);
```

Comment: The variables in our script defined as `global` do not have any value, they are empty, `0x0` "matrices". You would have do define the variables outside likewise as `global`. See, for instance, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68236140/global-variable-and-error-when-the-function-is-running-in-octave, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61846062/can-a-matlab-function-create-a-global-variable, or your documentation on the `global` keyword.

Comment: ooo clear! Thank You very much Mr. Lehmann.